# mySQL innodb_flush_method is a read only variable

Tags: mysql, database

I am using mySQL 5.6, I did a `show variables` in my database and I found out that my innodb_flush_method is blank and I want to set it to O_DSYNC . However, when I do a

```
set `innodb_flush_method`= `O_DSYNC`;
```

it say innodb_flush_method is a read only variable. Anyone know how do I set it to O_DSYNC ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit your `my.cnf` and put the value:

```
innodb_flush_method = O_DSYNC
```

Then restart your mysql server

Comment: @BeyondProgrammer if the answer was useful you should mark as correct